# Class App\Console\Commands\ExampleCommand does not exist when running php artisan tinker

Tags: laravel, tinker

Whenever I try to run `php artisan tinker` i get:
`ReflectionException  : Class App\Console\Commands\ExampleCommand does not exist`

While that file does indeed not exist, does it have to in order to run tinker?

Comment: try to use `php artisan clear-compiled`, you can see about it more from here https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/artisan#command-whitelist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to comment out the ExampleCommand line in the tinker.php file (line 17). Thank you @bhuncho for pointing out the command whitelist documentation, found it based on that!